# Laravel No Session Prevention

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5

Is it possible to access my Laravel application without obtaining a session? Right now I use sessions to prevent spam, and curious if I can just block out users that can't store sessions.

Comment: How do they supposed to log in without sessions?

Comment: I think what you want may actually be [csrf token protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf), which is built in in laravel if you use `web` middleware. There's no pro in disabling sessions to stop spam.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. So basically, I want to prevent users from accessing my application if their browser/client cannot store sessions. So I can prevent DDoS in a way.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish not to store any data for every request, you can choose `array` driver for sessions ([docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session)).

> array - sessions are stored in a PHP array and will not be persisted.

In `.env` file set `SESSION_DRIVER=array`